# left_join two dataframes using grep R

Tags: r, dplyr

Seen a number of posts demonstrating something close to what I need but none quite right.

I have a df of British postcodes:

```
df <- data.frame(ID = c("FK5 4JU", "FK2 9LD", "KA7 3XB", "ML1 2ND", "KA4 8DB", "ML1 5DD"),
                 var1 = c('a', 'b', 'c', 'c', 'd', 'e'),
                 var2 = c(1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1))
```

I'm trying to join it to another dataframe (df2) which includes only the first part of the postcode:

```
df2 <- data.frame(ID = c("FK5 4", "FK2 9", "KA7 3", "ML1 2", "KA4 8", "ML1 5"),
                  cat = c(6,6,4,5,4,5))
```

Ideally using a combination of left_join() and grepl().

Answer (score 2):

We can use the {powerjoin} package:

```r
library(powerjoin)
df |>
  power_left_join(df2,
                  by = ~ substr(.x$ID, 0 ,5) == .y$ID)

#>      ID.x var1 var2  ID.y cat
#> 1 FK5 4JU    a    1 FK5 4   6
#> 2 FK2 9LD    b    1 FK2 9   6
#> 3 KA7 3XB    c    1 KA7 3   4
#> 4 ML1 2ND    c    0 ML1 2   5
#> 5 KA4 8DB    d    1 KA4 8   4
#> 6 ML1 5DD    e    1 ML1 5   5
```

As @moodymudskipper suggested in the comments, we can also use `stringr::str_start()`:

```r
df |>
  power_left_join(df2,
                  by = ~ stringr::str_starts(.x$ID, .y$ID))
```

Data from OP:

```r
df <- data.frame(ID = c("FK5 4JU", "FK2 9LD", "KA7 3XB", "ML1 2ND", "KA4 8DB", "ML1 5DD"),
                 var1 = c('a', 'b', 'c', 'c', 'd', 'e'),
                 var2 = c(1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1))

df2 <- data.frame(ID = c("FK5 4", "FK2 9", "KA7 3", "ML1 2", "KA4 8", "ML1 5"),
                  cat = c(6,6,4,5,4,5))
```

<sup>Created on 2023-03-16 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: Thank you - whats the 0 and 5 doing in  ~ substr(.x$ID, 0 ,5) ?

Comment: I thought its easiest to subset the string in `df$ID` from the 0 to 5 character. We could also use a regex.

Comment: Here's an alternative : `power_left_join(df, df2, by = ~ stringr::str_starts(.x$ID, .y$ID))` this does the same thing, for a regex match (which is not really what we want here I think) we might use `str_detect()`

Answer (score 0):

We could use a fuzzy join here

```
library(fuzzyjoin)
regex_left_join(df, df2, by = 'ID')
```

-output

```
     ID.x var1 var2  ID.y cat
1 FK5 4JU    a    1 FK5 4   6
2 FK2 9LD    b    1 FK2 9   6
3 KA7 3XB    c    1 KA7 3   4
4 ML1 2ND    c    0 ML1 2   5
5 KA4 8DB    d    1 KA4 8   4
6 ML1 5DD    e    1 ML1 5   5
```